# className does not apply style

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here we go again. Let's see if you can decipher the riddle :D. So, the problem is the following. I have an external css file. I putted some 'specs' inside this file. I downloaded a plugin that make possible to link external css files into js files. So, in that way I can 'stylize' the JSX syntax inside that files. Everything ran great, but a problem appeared. If I declare a 'className' inside an element and I try to manipulate the properties of this element, nothing happens. But if I "call" the element by name( example: div {...} or footer{...} ) into the css file , the manipulation happens.

This is the code inside the JSX syntax:

```
<div className = "userlog_wrapper">.....</div>
```

..and this is the code inside the css file:

```
.userlog_wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 660px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. The solution is the following......if you are using the nextjs plugin for css [click on me](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css) .You need to write this inside the js file:

```
import css from ../wherever/the/file/are
```

and then, next to the className put this '= {css.nameOftheClass}'.
That's all, it should work.